# understanding some Promises code and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have the following code and as I havent worked with Promises a lot, then I am trying to understand, this question is more about an easy way to understand the code and not about a specific problem:

```
  private getRequestDigest(siteUrl: string): Promise<string> {
        const component: Reactwithmsgraphandsharepoint = this;
        return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject): void => {
          component.request(`${siteUrl}/_api/contextinfo`, 'POST').then((data: { FormDigestValue: string }): void => {
            resolve(data.FormDigestValue);
          }, (error: any): void => {
            reject(error);
          });
        });
       }


 private request<T>(url: string, method: string = 'GET', headers: any = null, data: any = null): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject): void => {
      const xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function (): void {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
          if (this.status === 200) {
            resolve(this.response as T);
          }
          else if (this.status >= 400) {
            reject({
              message: this.response['odata.error'].message.value,
              statusText: this.statusText,
              status: this.status
            });
          }
        }
      };

      xhr.open(method, url, true);
      if (headers === null) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=nometadata');
      }
      else {
        for (var header in headers) {
          if (headers.hasOwnProperty(header)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, headers[header]);
          }
        }
      }
      xhr.responseType = 'json';
      xhr.send(data);
    });
  }
```

1. On the get request method, the request method is executed, but with 2 parameters, but the signature receives more, how does it know which parameters? by argument order?, doesnt it need all arguments to be passed?
2. What is resolve and reject?
3. I understand than code in then is executed after the web request is executed, however in the then I dont see a function at all, I see  data: { FormDigestValue: string }): void => which is a syntax I dont understand.
4. What is resolve(this.response as T);     ? I come from C# and generics, so it looks like it can return anything?
5. And finally, can I put anything on a reject?

reject({
              message: this.response['odata.error'].message.value,
              statusText: this.statusText,
              status: this.status
            });

Comment: 1 - parameters method, headers and data have default values, so if you don't supply them, the defaults are used. 2 - resolve, reject are the callback functions you use to resolve or reject a promise, 3 - => is an arrow function, 4 - resolve is a Promise concept, 5 - yes, you can reject with anything you like

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) in `getRequestDigest`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted is pretty hard on the eyes, and not practical at all. It's not a good place to start learning about promises.

A *very good* place to start instead is MDN (the Mozilla Dev Network). It has excellent documentation on Javascript topics, including the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Some quick answers:

1. The `request` method takes 2 mandatory parameters, and the rest are optional, such as `headers: any = null`. This means that if `headers` (of type `any`) is not given as argument, it will default to `null`.
2. Both functions return a `Promise` object, which represents a future value or error. `resolve(value)` is used to signal that the `Promise` successfully became a value, and `reject(error)` is used to signal that something went wrong.
3. The code is executed after the request because it calls `.then(onValue, onError)` on the `Promise` returned from `request`. The functions passed to handle the 2 possible cases for the `Promise` are given as arguments:

   ```
   (data: { FormDigestValue: string }): void => { resolve(data.FormDigestValue) }
   (error: any): void => { reject(error) }
   ```

If the `Promise` returned from `request` is settled by `resolve(data)`, this function will in turn resolve its own `Promise` to `data.FormDigestValue`.

If the `Promise` return from `request` is setteled by `reject(error)`, this function will in turn reject its own `Promise` with the same `error`.

`getRequestDigest` is not very good code. As you'll learn by reading the MDN docs, `Promise` objects can be chained. The `new Promise()` constructor is harder to use, and not necessary in this case. It should instead read something like (skipping typescript here):

```
return component.request(url, method)
  .then(data => data.FormDigestValue)
```

`.then` will produce a new `Promise`, derived from the previous one (returned by `component.request`) to create the same result.

Did I mention to read the topic on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)? Seriously, great resource.

Comment: `request` takes **one** mandatory argument as far as I can see